# Verify the statements for Riemann-integrable function $f_n(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, riemann-integration

For each $n = 1, 2, \cdots$ a function $f_n(x)$ is defined so that it is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges $\forall \space x \in [a,b]$.

Which of the following statements are true?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)| = 0$$ 
$$\int_{a}^{b}\bigg(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |f_n(x)|\bigg) dx = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}|f_n(x)|dx = 0$$

**ATTEMPT**

**I.** $f_n$ is integrable, so it is bounded. Therefore, $\sup |f_n(x)|$ exists and equals to $|f_n(c)|, c\in [a, b]$. Since the series converges, $\lim f_n(x) = 0 \space \forall x \in [a, b]$. Hence $\lim \sup _{x \in [a, b]}|f_n(x)| =\lim|f_n(c)| = |0| = 0.$ Answers indicate that this is false, but I don't see where I am mistaken.

**II.** Recall that $\lim f_n(x) = 0 \space \forall x \in [a, b]$. Then $\lim |f_n(x)| = |0| = 0 \space \forall x \in [a, b]$. Therefore, the integrand is 0 on $[a, b]$, and so is the integral.

**III.** No idea.

It would be great if there was a counterexample.

Comment: A function being bounded does not imply that the maximum or minimum is obtained. What's more, the maximum needs not be obtained at the same point for different functions in the sequence.

Comment: Also, perhaps before discussing the statements, consider what you can conclude just from the given conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ f_n$ defined at $ [0,1]$ by
$$f_n(x)=x^n \; if \; x\ne 1 \; and \; f_n(1)=0$$

$$f_n \;  is \; Riemann\;  integrable\; at \; [0,1],$$

$$\sum f_n(x) \; converges \; \forall x\in[0,1]$$

but

$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)|=1$$
the first statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

As for the validity of the statements, **I** and **III** are both false. The example hamam-Abdallah gave, shows **I** is false. i.e,

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} x^n & ;0\leq x<1 
\\ 0 &; x=1 \end{cases} $$

A similar example can show that **III** is false. Notice that for the $f_n$ given in said example, we have

$$ \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1 x^ndx= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\vert_{x=0}^{x=1}=\frac{1}{n+1}. $$

So if you define

$$ g_n(x):=\begin{cases} (n+1)x^n &; 0\leq x<1 \\ 0 &; x=1 \end{cases}, $$

$\int_0^1 g_n(x)dx=1$, while $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ converges for all $x\in [0,1]$.

I would just add as a side-note, that both **I** and **III** were true, were you to assume further that $f_n$ ***uniformly converges*** to the function $f\equiv0$ in $[a,b]$.